# Why couldn't Natsu tell the difference between Gemini and Gray?

Tags: fairy-tail

In episode 58 Natsu encounters Gemini posing as Gray. Wouldn't her smell be different? Or does Gemini have the ability to mimic that too?

Comment: He couldn't tell because firstly because of motion sickness (remember he is on moving rafter) ,secondly Gray is his rival hence he couldn't think straight & natsu is somewhat dumb.

Comment: he wasnt on the raft at first...:"gray" was in the water before pulling off that dirty trick but natsu has a really good nose you would think he'd be able to tell the difference like he does a million other times unless gemini can completely copy another person or object including scent. didnt know if there was reference to something like this or its just one of those things that will stay a loophole.

Comment: sorry I have forgotten the Sean  I think the real reason maybe generally river washes away the sent of a person we see it often in Naruto. So natsu might subconsciously think the same.

Answer (score 1):

Gemini makes exact copies, even the celestial spirits couldnt tell the difference and they are bound by a magic contract. It makes sense that a perfect body copy would smell the same too. It does specifically say its an exact duplicate.